# Windows 10 Cortana Sign in?

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Is there another way to sign in to Cortana on Windows 10?

When she pops up asking about "Signing in to get to know you", the button is clickable, but nothing happens. After an extensive Google search, I'm still stuck on this. Multiple restarts and attempts, but I'm finally at the point I just need to ask everyone on SU.SE.

Note: I did not upgrade from any other version of Windows. This is a brand new computer with the OS actually starting as Windows 10.

Comment: Is your Windows logon tied to an MS account?  IF you create a new (non-MS) user and try it, does it behave any differently?

Comment: Couple questions.  What version of Windows 10 (Version 1511 or Version 1607)?  If you don't know, look up how you determine that, please don't guess.  Have you connected your local user account to a Microsoft Account, you need to do that, before you can use Cortana.  Update your question to include this information.  If you are not using Version 1607, perform the upgrade to Version 1607, typically minor problems like this are solved by doing so.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 As far as I know it is and from what I tested it doesn't. It uses the usual "Sign in with your e-mail", but I didn't connect it to the internet the first time I got it and signed in. Changing the user doesn't change it.